# TypeError while using positional argument in decorators

Tags: python-decorators

I am getting following error while performing a simple decorator code

"decorator_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'original_func'"

Appreciate if someone points at the issue, thanks.

Here is the code:

```
def decorator_func(original_func):
    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
       return original_func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper_func()

@decorator_func() #also tried without calling i.e. @decorater_func
def displayInfo_func(name, age):
        print('Display Info func ran with arguments ({}, {})'.format(name))

displayInfo_func
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is while returning wrapper function you are calling it and that too without any arguments.

```
def decorator_func(original_func):
    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
       return original_func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper_func #instead of wrapper_func()

@decorator_func() #also tried without calling i.e. @decorater_func
def displayInfo_func(name, age):
    print('Display Info func ran with arguments ({}, {})'.format(name))
```

Comment: Thanks much, That indeed works for me now :-). Thanks alot again.

Comment: Done. Really deserve it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I upvoted, but not enough reputation (less than 15), since I am new.

Comment: Cool, it worked. Upvoted and now it's showing "1". Thanks much.